# plot result of nonlinear differential equation

Tags: plotting, nonlinear, differential-equations

```
x1'[t] == x2[t]
x2'[t] == -4*y2[t]*y1[t]^2 + (2*x2[t]*y2[t])/y1[t] - (y2[t]^2*y1[t]^2)/
   x1[t]^3
y1'[t] == y2[t]
y2'[t] == 
 4*x2[t]*x1[t]^2 + (2*y2[t]*x2[t])/x1[t] - (x2[t]^2*x1[t]^2)/y1[t]^3
```

How can I plot of x1 versus x2, x1 versus y1, x1 versus y2, y1 versus y2?

Please help me ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

> You are trying to solve a set of Ordinary differential equation but you forgot to set up initial conditions.

This is just to  get you started.

Your equation

```
 eqn = { x1'[t] == x2[t],
  x2'[t] == -4*y2[t]*y1[t]^2 + (2*x2[t]*y2[t])/
     y1[t] - (y2[t]^2*y1[t]^2)/x1[t]^3,
  y1'[t] == y2[t],
  y2'[t] ==  4*x2[t]*x1[t]^2 + (2*y2[t]*x2[t])/x1[t] - (x2[t]^2*x1[t]^2)/y1[t]^3}
```

Some initial condition that I randomly chose as you forgot to specify them:

```
ics = {x1[0] == 1, x2[0] == 2, y1[0] == 1, y2[0] == 1};
```

The numerical solution

```
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{eqn, ics}], {x1, y1, x2, y2}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

One of the plots you requested

```
 ParametricPlot[{x1[t], x2[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 1},AxesLabel -> {x1[t], x2[t]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Map[ParametricPlot[# /. sol, {t, 0, 1}] &,
   {{x2[t], x1[t]}, {y1[t], x1[t]},
    {y2[t], x1[t]}, {y2[t], y1[t]}}] // Partition[#, 2] & // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: how can I plot x1-x2 on the same plot with different initial conditions? please help me

Comment: ok I have done thank you.